# Can´t deploy my .war file in tomcat 7 using ANT and via the tomcat-manager

Tags: ant, tomcat7, web-deployment

I'm having problems when deploying my web application in my tomcat 7 web server. I've tried by deploying my war file via ant and I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.nio.file.TempFileHelper
 [java]     at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanJar(TldConfig.java:507)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.access$100(TldConfig.java:59)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig$TldJarScannerCallback.scan(TldConfig.java:332)
 [java]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:234)
 [java]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:159)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:306)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:925)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1343)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:294)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1235)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1393)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1403)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1382)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The web application's folder is created in my tomcat webapps folder, but when trying to access the application via:

> http://localhost:8080/Natura_WEB

I get a 404 error telling that the application doesn't exist.

I also tried deploying my application via the tomcat-manager and it says that the application was deployed correctly, but it doesn't come in the tomcat application listing, but the folder is also created in the webapps directory and when I try to access in the browser I get the same error that before.

I know this is definitively a tomcat failure because I try to deploy exactly the same war file in another computer and it worked perfectly.

Any suggestions about how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not getting deployed properly, because it is not able to locate the dependency jars.

it is not able to find this class "java.nio.file.TempFileHelper"

Try to locate that class, figure out which jar contains that file.

and put that jar in WEB-INF/lib and try deploying again. it should work.

Comment: The curious thing is why is the same war file works perfectly in one machine but not on the other? Does this have to do with the JDK installed?

Comment: may be the common tomcat lib directory of that machine contains tht jar and is able to locate the class into the global context. check the common tomcat lib of that machine whether it contains that jar.